# Jquery each() always using last objects attribute

Tags: jquery, object, attributes, each, attr

I'm trying to loop through all the elements on my page with a certain class and then set the styles colour dynamically.
The problem is that it is always using the last objects colour attribute, and I dont know why, as when I log the colour its always different?
Here's my code:

```
var find= $("."+id);
find.each(function(index, element) {
    var colour = $(this).attr('colour');

    var top = $("."+id + ".top");
    var mid = $("."+id + ".middle");
    var bot = $("."+id + ".bottom");
    top.attr("style","border-bottom: 27px solid "+colour);

    mid.attr("style","background:"+colour);

    bot.attr("style","border-top: 27px solid "+colour);

});
```

Anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks a lot!

Edit:
Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="hex-row">
 <a href="">
  <div class="hex ">
   <div class="top image" colour="#E1BB4E"></div>
   <div class="middle image" colour="#E1BB4E"></div>
   <div class="bottom image" colour="#E1BB4E"></div>
 </div>
</a>
<a href="">
 <div class="hex ">
  <div class="top publishing" colour="#A34F70"></div>
  <div class="middle publishing" colour="#A34F70"></div>
  <div class="bottom publishing" colour="#A34F70"></div>
</div>
</a>
</div>
```

The problem is not with finding the divs- the code is targeting the correct elements - but it's setting them all as the same color, its supposed to grab each of the elements attr('colour') and use that color.

Comment: what is represented by `id` in `$("."+id)`?

Comment: and `colour` is not a valid `attribute` use `data` attributes instead. The code you posted in not sufficient for us to help you. Show more.

Comment: Id in $("."+id) represents either 'image' or 'publishing' depending on which button has been clicked.

Comment: @matt - I've just updated my answer. It should work!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this happens because you don't change the 'id' variable. So every iteration you set new color to the same elements and at the end the color equal to the "colour" attribute of the last element in "find" variable.